# Is there a way of disabling then recording of video on a website?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, vimeo, video-recording, realplayer

Is there an option or more security features where we can make our videos non downloable i.e. using realplayer record option or other, basically preventing third party apps from recording video on a website.

We will be using Vimeo Plus. Any ideas or thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search for alternatives. The best way to tackle this is by having a watermark or a background image of your company logo or a small logo at the corner or something.This is what major TV channels do.

Comment: Hi Ripul, Thanks for your response. This is definitely worth considering. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of services like netflix, which go to great lengths to provide and control the player software, No. In most cases, if the video is being displayed on a client (ie. via browser), then it is available to be saved locally, or even to be captured by screen capture software. To be sure, the likes of youtube and vimeo try to make it non-trivial ... but there's easily available software to download the videos in almost all cases.

unless someone else knows something I don't :-)